# iOS APP，open and close a specific View each time ,Why Main function takes up close to 20M memory？

Tags: ios, memory, allocation

In the APP operation, I opened and closed several times a particular View, found that the incremental memory every 25MB or so, through the Allocation tool for testing and found that in each Generations main function takes up about 19MB, why main function will Occupy such a large memory? Also in the process of opening and closing a View, the main function of the implementation of what it means?

[image: The Allocation info1]

[image: The Allocation info2]

Thanks everyone！！！

Comment: The main function is the main thread which loads the UI everytime the view is reloaded. Chances are that you may have some function code specific to your app in the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main function is the main thread which loads the UI everytime the view is reloaded. Chances are that you may have some function code specific to your app in the main thread

To free the memory overtime you close the view you can make a function which deallocates all the properties declared in the view Controller. Hope this helps

This can be done like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.declaredProperty1 = nil;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,problem has been solved, because there is a very hidden circular reference.

Comment: Superb. Happy coding!